# Where to download Fedora 16

Tags: linux, fedora

I am having a really hard time finding a place to download Fedora 16 64 bit distribution are there still places that have links up for 16th version instead of 17? A Virtual image for VirtualBox would be good as well.

Comment: Where have you looked? [Fedora Public FTP Mirros](http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/16/x86_64/) might help.

Comment: Why do you want an outdated version?

Comment: Part of the requirements for an app was to test it specifically on Fedora 16 so it was one of those "because the manager said so"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora archives their old versions [at archive.fedoraproject.org](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/). So, for F16, try [this](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora) (install DVD - choose the appropriate directory for your architecture) or [there](http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/16/Live/) (live-CDs).